# How to have multiple infinite ranges in list comprehensions?

Tags: haskell

In haskell I have a list comprehension like this:

```
sq = [(x,y,z) | x <- v, y <- v, z <- v, x*x + y*y == z*z, x < y, y < z]
    where v = [1..]
```

However when I try `take 10 sq`, it just freezes...
Is there a way to handle multiple infinite ranges?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers explaining the problem, here is an alternative solution, generalized to work with [`level-monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/level-monad/0.3.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Levels.html) and [`stream-monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stream-monad/0.4.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Stream.html) that lend themselves for searches over infinite search spaces (It is also compatible with the list monad and [`logict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/logict/0.6/doc/html/Control-Monad-Logic.html), but those won't play nicely with infinite search spaces, as you already found out):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}

module Triples where

import Control.Monad

sq :: MonadPlus m => m (Int, Int, Int)
sq = [(x, y, z) | x <- v, y <- v, z <- v, x*x + y*y == z*z, x < y, y < z]
    where v = return 0 `mplus` v >>= (return . (1+))
```

Now, for a fast breadth first search:

```
*Triples> :m +Control.Monad.Stream
*Triples Control.Monad.Stream> take 10 $ runStream sq
[(3,4,5),(6,8,10),(5,12,13),(9,12,15),(8,15,17),(12,16,20),(7,24,25),
(15,20,25),(10,24,26),(20,21,29)]
```

Alternatively:

```
*Triples> :m +Control.Monad.Levels
*Triples Control.Monad.Levels> take 5 $ bfs sq   -- larger memory requirements
[(3,4,5),(6,8,10),(5,12,13),(9,12,15),(8,15,17)]
*Triples Control.Monad.Levels> take 5 $ idfs sq  -- constant space, slower, lazy
[(3,4,5),(5,12,13),(6,8,10),(7,24,25),(8,15,17)]
```

Answer (score 5):

List comprehensions are translated into nested applications of the `concatMap` function:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap f xs = concat (map f xs)

concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat [] = []
concat (xs:xss) = xs ++ concat xss

-- Shorter definition:
--
-- > concat = foldr (++) []
```

Your example is equivalent to this:

```
sq = concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> concatMap (\z -> test x y z) v) v) v
    where v = [1..]
          test x y z = 
              if x*x + y*y == z*z
              then if x < y
                   then if y < z
                        then [(x, y, z)]
                        else []
                   else []
              else []
```

This is basically a "nested loops" approach; it'll first try `x = 1, y = 1, z = 1`, then move on to `x = 1, y = 1, z = 2` and so on, until it tries all of the list's elements as values for `z`; only then can it move on to try combinations with `y = 2`.

But of course you can see the problem—since the list is infinite, we never run out of values to try for `z`.  So the combination `(3, 4, 5)` can only occur after infinitely many other combinations, which is why your code loops forever.

To solve this, we need to generate the triples in a smarter way, such that for any possible combination, the generator reaches it after some finite number of steps.  Study this code (which handles only pairs, not triples):

```
-- | Take the Cartesian product of two lists, but in an order that guarantees
-- that all combinations will be tried even if one or both of the lists is 
-- infinite:
cartesian :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
cartesian [] _ = []
cartesian _ [] = []
cartesian (x:xs) (y:ys) = 
    [(x, y)] ++ interleave3 vertical horizontal diagonal
        where 
          -- The trick is to split the problem into these four pieces:
          --
          -- |(x0,y0)| (x0,y1) ... horiz
          -- +-------+------------
          -- |(x1,y0)| .
          -- |   .   |  .
          -- |   .   |   .
          -- |   .   |    . 
          --   vert         diag
          vertical = map (\x -> (x,y)) xs
          horizontal = map (\y -> (x,y)) ys
          diagonal = cartesian xs ys


interleave3 :: [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave3 xs ys zs = interleave xs (interleave ys zs)

interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave xs [] = xs
interleave [] ys = ys
interleave (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys
```

To understand this code (and fix it if I messed up!) look at [this blog entry on how to count infinite sets](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/counting-infinity), and at the fourth diagram in particular—the function is an algorithm based on that "zigzag"!

I just tried a simple version of your `sq` using this; it finds `(3,4,5)` almost instantly, but then takes very long to get to any other combination (in GHCI at least).  But I think the key lessons to take away from this are:

1. List comprehensions just don't work well for nested infinite lists.
2. Don't spend too much time playing around with list comprehensions.  Everything that they can do, functions like `map`, `filter` and `concatMap` can do—plus there are many other useful functions in [the list library](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html), so concentrate your effort on that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code freeze because yours predicate will never been satisfied.
Why ?

Let's take an example without any predicate to understand.

```
>>> let v = [1..] in take 10 $ [ (x, y, z) | x <- v,  y <- v, z <- v ] 
[(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,1,4),(1,1,5),(1,1,6),(1,1,7),(1,1,8),(1,1,9),(1,1,10)]
```

As you see x and y will always be evaluated to 1 as z will never stop to rise.
Then your predicate can't be.

Any workaround ?

Try "Nested list" comprehension.

```
>>> [[ fun x y | x <- rangeX, predXY] | y  <- rangeY, predY ]
```

Or parallel list comprehension which can be activated using,

```
>>> :set -XParallelListComp
```

lookup on the [doc](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#parallel-list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you'll have to come up with an order in which to generate the numbers. The following generates the numbers you want; note that the `x < y` test can be replaced by generating only `y` that are `>x` and similarly for `z` (which is determined once `x` and `y` are bound):

```
[(x, y, z) | total <- [1..]
           , x <- [1..total-2]
           , y <- [x..total-1]
           , z <- [total - x - y]
           , x*x + y*y == z*z]
```

Comment: the output shouldn't be that, the constraint is x^2+y^2=z^2 and no same sets even regardless of order.

Comment: I think this is missing some guards or something, based on the code in the question, I think they want only the Pythagorean triples.

Comment: @omega: rewrote the whole thing.